# In the data can not use data's variable

Tags: vue.js

In the data can not use data's variable.

In my `data`:

```
data(){
  return {
    value: '',

    a: {b:'123'},
    c: [
      this.a.b,
      "456"
    ]
  }
},
```

in my template:

```
<span v-if="a && a.b"> {{c[0]}} </span>
```

but seems in the data, I can not use `this.a.b`, I also tried use `this.$data.a.b`, still do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better to use [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to achieve this.
Your trying to use other field value of one object while it's been creating yet.